# Convert a hashmap to a json string in spring-boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I am creating a spring-boot application and I want to be able to return the whole content of a hashmap as a json string. How do I do that?

My hashmap looks like the following:

```
private static final Map<String,Animal> animalMap= new HashMap<String,Animal>();
```

The function

```
@RequestMapping(value="/animals", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showAllAnimals() {

        // In here I want to return the content of my hashmap as a Json String
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/animals", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String,Animal> showAllAnimals() {
    return animalMap;
}
```

Comment: I missed the @ResponseBody when I tried something similar earlier. Thanks!